# Which variables to pass to a tensor flow predictor for tf.feature_coloumns using wide and deep learning model?

Tags: tensorflow

I've been trying out the wide and deep learning example from the tensor flow site: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep

I can train and evaluate the model and even predict within that same process but I can't seem to figure out what input I need to pass into the predictor function when I try to do a prediction from a model that was saved and then reloaded via the predictor.from_saved_model function.

My feature columns and model look like this which runs fine:

```
term = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("term", unique_terms['term'].tolist())
name = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("name", unique_name['name'].tolist())

base_columns = [term, cust_name]

crossed_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.crossed_column(["term", "cust_name"], hash_bucket_size=100000),    
]    

deep_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column(term),
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column(cust_name),    
]

model_dir = export_dir
search_model = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
    model_dir=model_dir,
    linear_feature_columns=crossed_columns,
    dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
    dnn_hidden_units=[100, 50])
```

I saved the model like this:

```
feature_columns = crossed_columns + deep_columns
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)
export_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
servable_model_dir = export_dir
servable_model_path = search_model.export_savedmodel(servable_model_dir, export_input_fn)
```

And then I load it back from file like this:

```
predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(export_dir)
predictions = predict_fn({'X':[10]})
```

The predict_fn is expecting a dictionary with key "inputs" not "x" except I am not sure what the value of "inputs" should be. Can anyone help me out on this please?